# a href link of an image not taking up all image size in a box

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a list of menus, each menu links to another page using a picture.

**First I wrote the CSS**

```css
    .gallery {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ffd700;
      float: left;
      width: 140px;
    }
    
    .gallery:hover {
      border: 1px solid #777;
    }
    
    .gallery img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Second, I made the HTML code.




Koi Gate

```
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere">
      <img src="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere" alt="Demo Koi Gate Habanero" class="wp-image-262"/></img>
    </a>
  <div class="desc">Hot Hot Fruit</div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere">
      <img src="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere" alt="Demo Koi Gate Habanero" class="wp-image-262"/></img>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Wealth Inn</div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere">
      <img src="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere" alt="Demo Slot Fa Cai Shen" class="wp-image-262"/></img>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Fa Cai Shen</div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere">
      <img src="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere" alt="Demo Slot Wild Trucks" class="wp-image-262"/></img>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Wild Trucks</div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere">
      <img src="hxxp://imnotputtingmyurlhere" alt="Demo Slot Zeus" class="wp-image-262"/></img>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Zeus</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

However, the result is the links are not taking the full space to the whole picture used. Would anyone please help me?

Comment: Its working as expected https://jsfiddle.net/mswqr9gk/

Answer (score 0):

On mouse over `a` is taking whole `img`, but when you inspect it look smaller. That is because `img` tag is by default `display: inline-block;` and `a` tag is `display: inline;`.

[image]

In your example for `a` you have to place `display: block;` and it will cover whole img tag.
Div with name `<div class="desc">Zeus</div>` is outside of `a` tag

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I added these line to .a but it doesnt work:  .a {display: block;}

Comment: @Mryoumightnotknowwho don't use `a` with dot for style, because `a` is a tag not class. Write it without dot like this `a {display: block;}` I changed answer with more info

Comment: Nope, still not working. It does work when on dekstop view but when im checking from mobile it doesnt work

Comment: If its is not allowed to put links here then I would like to apologize, but here is my site> https://www.anzellottisound.com/ maybe you could help me better if you could see the full code?

Comment: please help, this is getting frustating

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Html

```css
.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffd700;
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
}
.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg" alt="Demo Koi Gate Habanero" class="wp-image-262"/>
      <div class="desc">Hot Hot Fruit</div>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg" alt="Demo Koi Gate Habanero" class="wp-image-262"/>
      <div class="desc">Wealth Inn</div>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg" alt="Demo Slot Fa Cai Shen" class="wp-image-262"/>
     <div class="desc">Fa Cai Shen</div>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg" alt="Demo Slot Wild Trucks" class="wp-image-262"/>
      <div class="desc">Wild Trucks</div>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/black-demo-icon-white-background-black-demo-icon-116555294.jpg" alt="Demo Slot Zeus" class="wp-image-262"/>
      <div class="desc">Zeus</div>
  </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Doesnt work, sir. It does work on dekstop, but when I open it through mobile it just simply doesnt.

Comment: you have to end the 'a' tag before gallery class div then the link is apply for both image and text and remove </img> we never close the img tag like this

Comment: it still doesnt work